# SAS Importing a delimited file where missing values are periods

Tags: sas

I'm importing a very large .txt file that is pipe delimited. In the .txt, missing variables are marked with a . (like a missing numeric in SAS). When I am importing numeric variables though, SAS sees the . and returns the error "Invalid data for  at line " because it thinks its suddenly character. Is there a way I can tell SAS to read those periods as missing?

Some sample code:

```
data USE.NavENC    ;
    %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
    infile "path" delimiter = '|' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=13106 firstobs=2 ;
       informat PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER $32. ;
       informat DATE_SERVICE_FROM yymmdd10. ;
       informat DATE_SERVICE_TO yymmdd10. ;
       informat PATIENT_UMPI $10. ;
       informat PATIENT_AGE $5. ;
       informat DATE_PATIENT_DOB yymmdd10. ;
       informat PATIENT_SEX $7. ;
       informat PATIENT_HOME_ZIP_5_DIGIT $5. ;
       informat PATIENT_HOME_COUNTY_NAME $64. ;
       informat FINANCIAL_CLASS_CODE $8. ;
       informat PRIMARY_PAYER_PLAN_CODE $12. ;
       informat PRIMARY_PAYER_PLAN_NAME $100. ;
       informat CHARGES_TOTAL best32. ;
       informat PAYMENTS_TOTAL best32. ;
       informat ADJUSTMENTS_TOTAL best32. ;
       informat ACCOUNT_BALANCE_TOTAL best32. ;
       informat COST_TOTAL best32. ;
       informat COST_VARIABLE $24. ;
       informat COST_FIXED $24. ;
       informat UNITS best32. ;
       informat COST_DIR_VAR_TOTAL best32. ;
       informat COST_DIR_FIX_TOTAL best32. ;
       informat COST_IND_VAR_TOTAL best32. ;
       informat COST_IND_FIX_TOTAL best32. ;
       informat PATIENT_HOME_ADDRESS $57. ;
       informat PATIENT_HOME_CITY $36. ;
       informat PATIENT_HOME_STATE_NAME $37. ;
       format PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER $32. ;
       format DATE_SERVICE_FROM yymmdd10. ;
       format DATE_SERVICE_TO yymmdd10. ;
       format PATIENT_UMPI $8. ;
       format PATIENT_AGE $5. ;
       format DATE_PATIENT_DOB yymmdd10. ;
       format PATIENT_SEX $7. ;
       format PATIENT_HOME_ZIP_5_DIGIT $5. ;
       format PATIENT_HOME_COUNTY_NAME $64. ;
       format FINANCIAL_CLASS_CODE $4. ;
       format PRIMARY_PAYER_PLAN_CODE $12. ;
       format PRIMARY_PAYER_PLAN_NAME $58. ;
       format CHARGES_TOTAL best12. ;
       format PAYMENTS_TOTAL best12. ;
       format ADJUSTMENTS_TOTAL best32. ;
       format ACCOUNT_BALANCE_TOTAL best32. ;
       format COST_TOTAL best12. ;
       format COST_VARIABLE $24. ;
       format COST_FIXED $24. ;
       format UNITS best12. ;
       format COST_DIR_VAR_TOTAL best12. ;
       format COST_DIR_FIX_TOTAL best12. ;
       format COST_IND_VAR_TOTAL best12. ;
       format COST_IND_FIX_TOTAL best12. ;
       format PATIENT_HOME_ADDRESS $57. ;
       format PATIENT_HOME_CITY $36. ;
       format PATIENT_HOME_STATE_NAME $37. ;
    input
                PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
                DATE_SERVICE_FROM
                DATE_SERVICE_TO
                PATIENT_UMPI  $
                PATIENT_AGE $
                DATE_PATIENT_DOB
                PATIENT_SEX  $
                PATIENT_HOME_ZIP_5_DIGIT  $
                PATIENT_HOME_COUNTY_NAME  $
                FINANCIAL_CLASS_CODE  $
                PRIMARY_PAYER_PLAN_CODE
                PRIMARY_PAYER_PLAN_NAME  $
                CHARGES_TOTAL
                PAYMENTS_TOTAL
                ADJUSTMENTS_TOTAL  $
                ACCOUNT_BALANCE_TOTAL  $
                COST_TOTAL
                COST_VARIABLE $
                COST_FIXED $
                UNITS
                COST_DIR_VAR_TOTAL
                COST_DIR_FIX_TOTAL
                COST_IND_VAR_TOTAL
                COST_IND_FIX_TOTAL
                PATIENT_HOME_ADDRESS  $
                PATIENT_HOME_CITY  $
                PATIENT_HOME_STATE_NAME  $
    ;
    if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
    run;
```

The error in quesiton:

```
NOTE: Invalid data for ADJUSTMENTS_TOTAL in line 19 109-112.
19        REDACTED|REDACTRED|REDACTED|REDACTED|REDACTED|REDACTED|RECATED|31204|REDACTED|101|11700113|HU
      91  MANA MA|0.00|0.00|NULL|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|1.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|4217 REDACTED|REDACTED|REDACTED
     181  RGIA 184
PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER=REDACTRED DATE_SERVICE_FROM=REDACTED DATE_SERVICE_TO=REDACTRED
PATIENT_UMPI=REDACTED PATIENT_AGE=REDACTED DATE_PATIENT_DOB=REDACTED PATIENT_SEX=REDACTED
PATIENT_HOME_ZIP_5_DIGIT=REDACTED PATIENT_HOME_COUNTY_NAME=REDACTED FINANCIAL_CLASS_CODE=101
PRIMARY_PAYER_PLAN_CODE=11700113 PRIMARY_PAYER_PLAN_NAME=HUMANA MA CHARGES_TOTAL=0 PAYMENTS_TOTAL=0
ADJUSTMENTS_TOTAL=. ACCOUNT_BALANCE_TOTAL=0 COST_TOTAL=0 COST_VARIABLE=0.00 COST_FIXED=0.00 UNITS=1
COST_DIR_VAR_TOTAL=0 COST_DIR_FIX_TOTAL=0 COST_IND_VAR_TOTAL=0 COST_IND_FIX_TOTAL=0
PATIENT_HOME_ADDRESS=REDACTED PATIENT_HOME_CITY=REDACTED PATIENT_HOME_STATE_NAME=REDACTED _ERROR_=1
_N_=18
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure about sas specifically, but usually if you have a character type that doesn't work, its often because it is used in that language for something, so it assumes you are trying to use that code, and errors out.  So you have to "terminate" what ever character that is, usually by doubling it up.  I wonder if the . its self is causing it to error?

Comment: I dont really understand any of what you said lol, SAS is really the only language/program I use so I dont have a lot of external context

Comment: If you're only reading in one column why do you have a delimiter?

Comment: Periods are not the issue, something else is, please post your log and full code if this is a portion. See example in answer which I will delete shortly.

Comment: Your text file has the string NULL instead of an actual `null` value. In a delimited file a null value is not marked by the string NULL but by just having no characters between the delimiters.

Comment: Do you know how to handle the NULL?

Answer (score 2):

The file is using the string NULL in fields that you want to read as numeric.  If you don't mind the notes in the log then result will be a missing value.

If it is never possible that NULL is a valid value for a variable you could add logic to your data step to remove them from the input line before trying to read the variables.

Plus you don't have to write code that is as ugly as the stuff that PROC IMPORT generates.

```
data USE.NavENC    ;
  infile "path" dsd dlm='|' truncover firstobs=2 ;
  length 
    PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER $32
    DATE_SERVICE_FROM 8
    DATE_SERVICE_TO 8
    PATIENT_UMPI $10
    PATIENT_AGE $5
    DATE_PATIENT_DOB 8
    PATIENT_SEX $7
    PATIENT_HOME_ZIP_5_DIGIT $5
    PATIENT_HOME_COUNTY_NAME $64
    FINANCIAL_CLASS_CODE $8
    PRIMARY_PAYER_PLAN_CODE $12
    PRIMARY_PAYER_PLAN_NAME $100
    CHARGES_TOTAL 8
    PAYMENTS_TOTAL 8
    ADJUSTMENTS_TOTAL 8
    ACCOUNT_BALANCE_TOTAL 8
    COST_TOTAL 8
    COST_VARIABLE $24
    COST_FIXED $24
    UNITS 8
    COST_DIR_VAR_TOTAL 8
    COST_DIR_FIX_TOTAL 8
    COST_IND_VAR_TOTAL 8
    COST_IND_FIX_TOTAL 8
    PATIENT_HOME_ADDRESS $57
    PATIENT_HOME_CITY $36
    PATIENT_HOME_STATE_NAME $37
  ;
  informat DATE_SERVICE_FROM DATE_SERVICE_TO DATE_PATIENT_DOB yymmdd10. ;
  format DATE_SERVICE_FROM DATE_SERVICE_TO DATE_PATIENT_DOB yymmdd10. ;
  input @;
  _infile_=tranwrd(cats('|',_infile_,'|'),'|NULL|','||');
  input @2 PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER -- PATIENT_HOME_STATE_NAME;
run;
```